# What are Instruments in Xcode and where can I find tutorials about them?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

Can any one tell me what Intruments are in Xcode?  Are there any tutorials or videos for learning about Instruments, such as the Lynda iPhone SDK Essential Training tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is Apple's profiler framework and visualization application. It works with any XCode supported language and device (C, C++, Objective C).

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a [list of features](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/features.html) for Instruments on their developer tools page.  It's not necessarily Objective-C related, but it is a set of tools for helping you to find bugs and improve your application's performance.

Answer (score 1):

Apple also has a [user guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for Instruments -- it starts off with a list of what you can do with Instruments, and then tells you how to do these things.

Answer (score 0):

[Instruments User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

#### WWDC 2010

- [Session 304](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=304) - What's New in Instruments
- [Session 306](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=306) - Automating User Interface Testing with Instruments
- [Session 309](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=309) - Advanced Performance Analysis with Instruments
- [Session 311](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=311) - Advanced Memory Analysis with Instruments

#### WWDC 2011

- [Session 310](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=310) - What's New In Instruments
- [Session 312](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=312) - iOS Performance and Power Optimization with Instruments

#### WWDC 2012

- [Session 409](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=409) - Learning Instruments